# Displaying users name only on week days in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to display users name only on weekdays for that my views are like this:

```
= calendar @date do |date|
    = date.day
    - @leaves.each do |leave|
      - if (leave.from_date..leave.to_date).include? date
        %p.name= link_to leave.user.name, leave
```

I am using full_calendar gem. but it is displaying name of users on saturday and sunday also. So, I want to restrict displaying users name on weekend. Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

You can update your if condition as follows:

```
- if !date.saturday? && !date.sunday? && date.in?(leave.from_date..leave.to_date)
```

A cleaner way would be to add a methods to Date class:

```
class Date
  def weekend?
    saturday? || sunday?
  end  

  def weekday?
    !weekend?
  end  
end
```

and then

```
- if date.weekday? && date.in?(leave.from_date..leave.to_date)
```

Comment: After adding this - if !date.saturday? && !date.sunday? && date.in?
It is throwing syntax error.

Comment: I got the answer by adding this linel - if !(date.on_weekend?).
btw thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the following check on date.

```
today = Date.today
if !(today.saturday? || today.sunday)
 display user
end
```